# Hide Secret API Key in electron app while using mongodb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, security, electron, realm

I am currently looking into creating an electron application using next js, monogodb and realm.

After looking through the mongodb documentation i came accross the integration guide "Quick start with electron using react". I found this guide to be very informative but I am trying to understand if the company made an oversight when creating this guide.

guide: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/node/integrations/electron-cra/#std-label-node-electron-cra-client-quick-start

The guide has this boiler code which enables you to write to the realm.

```
const app = new Realm.App({ id: "<Your App ID>" }); // create a new instance of the Realm.App
async function run() {
  // login with an anonymous credential
  await app.logIn(Realm.Credentials.anonymous());
  const DogSchema = {
      name: "Dog",
      properties: {
        _id: 'int',
        name: "string",
        age: "int",
      },
      primaryKey: '_id'
  };
  const realm = await Realm.open({
    schema: [DogSchema],
    sync: {
      user: app.currentUser,
      partitionValue: "myPartition",
    },
  });
  // The myPartition realm is now synced to the device. You can
  // access it through the `realm` object returned by `Realm.open()`
  // write to the realm
}
run().catch(err => {
  console.error("Failed to open realm:", err)
});
```

To write to the realm you need to put your app id into the code (as shown above) which makes sense. The thing that doesn't make sense is if this is a electron application couldn't someone just find this id and then be able to write and delete from your realm. Is this an oversight or does mongodb want the user to figure out how to secretly store that app id themselves.

Since its a guide that specifically talks about electron I would think they would take security into account and put that into the guide.

I maybe completely off base with this question, but I just want to understand if it is even possible to secretly store your app id / api key in an electron app. If its not possible without using another api to fetch the key on start then is this really an oversight? or can that id be kept has plain text and still have the app be secure.

I understand that firebase and amplify also have this problem when working with electron. I figured since mongodb has a guide that directly references electron they would have found an easy fix to this problem.

Comment: An app id is simply an identifier that lets Realm know what app the code wants to work with. There is no security involved and just because someone has an app id, doesn't mean they can do anything with your data. Realm requires authentication (if implemented) and there are Rules that can be put in place to control what access users have e.g. Anonymous users can read only. This is also true of Firebase; the apiKey just identifies your Firebase project on the Google servers. It is not a security risk for someone to know it. Realm also offers encryption if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [safeStorage API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/safe-storage) to store your app id on disk and prevent it from being accessed by other users.

Comment: While safely storing an app id using a third party library is fine, it really has no impact on the question. App ID's are not a security risk - see my comment to the question.

Answer (score 1):

To me the article outlines code purely for learning purpose , because in production anonymous login is never enabled.

In applications such sensitive data are never part of the source code instead they are loaded in memory at runtime . This can be a good starting point for you [Best practices to store sensitive information in Electron desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63748729/best-practices-to-store-sensitive-information-in-electron-desktop-application)

Comment: To add a bit more info, in Realm the app id is not sensitive data and has no impact on security. All Realm apps have an app id and there is no security risk exposing it. The caveat is if the developer fails to implement [Permissions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/rules/#std-label-mongodb-rules) which limits/controls what data users can access.